# Matrix fraction decomposition of an integral

Tags: integration, matrices

I understand this can be solved using matrix fraction decomposition. However I could not find any information on this topic. Please help.

$$
\int_r^s e^{-At}BB' (e^{-At})'dt\,.
$$

Where $A$ is an $n \times n$ and $B$ is an $n \times 1$ matrix.

Comment: Question: What does $B'$ mean? Is it the transpose of $B$?

Comment: @Braindead. Yes it is the transpose B.

Comment: Cross-posted on MO: [q164883](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164883/matrix-fraction-decomposition-of-an-integral).